# AGM marker cluster on cluster click

Tags: angular, angular-google-maps

I am using [js-marker-clusterer](https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/js-marker-clusterer/index.html). Is here any way how to get list of clustered markers on cluster click? Or maybe with native google maps?

Comment: Did you get any solution or workaround for this?

Comment: nope. It looks like library has no such feature, so I used native google maps

Comment: @TomP, How this was implemented with native google maps? Any reference for this would help. Thanks in Advance!!